# Looking for some sort of "for all" function to use within my if operator for generating primes

Tags: python

So I've used python in the context of loading .csv files to make plots for various graphs, but now I'm trying to get into general coding. Hence, I want to make a function that generates prime numbers without looking up full examples on it beforehand. I know what I want the code to do, but don't know how to execute it.

This is my code so far:

```
prime = [1,2,3]
nextNum = prime[-1] + 1
limit = 600
num = 0

while num < limit:
    for n in prime[1:round((nextNum)**(1/2))]:
        if nextNum % n != 0:
            prime.append(nextNum) 
            nextNum += 1
        else:
            nextNum += 1
        num += 1

print(prime)
```

This is intended to print a list of primes up to 600. However, it's currently printing [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14...]. I believe the issue is that the if operator just goes with n values one by one, while I want it to consider them all at once. Something along the lines of "if nexNum % all(n) != 0". Except all() doesn't really do what I want. I was also thinking of using something like "for all...", but apparently that's not a thing either.

So how can I incorporate this detail without completely changing my code? Any hints would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Check this though: `prime[1:round((nextNum)**(1/2))]`. That returns the elements whose **indices** are between 1 and `round((nextNum)**(1/2))`. Maybe you want the elements whose **values** are between those endpoints?

Comment: Also, 1 is **not** prime. You might want to leave it out of the prime list.

Comment: how many even numbers are prime

Comment: why do you have `nextNum += 1` in both `then` and `else`

Comment: write a generator that produces the primes you want to test with

Answer (score 0):

Following the guide from slothrop on how to implement the all() function in this scenario helped in fixing the code to work as intended. I've also implemented the fact that 1 is not a prime.

Below is the adjusted code:

```
prime = [2]
nextNum = prime[-1] + 1
limit = 600
num = 0

while num < limit:
    rang = prime[0:round((nextNum)**(1/2))]
    for n in rang:
        if all(nextNum % n != 0 for n in rang):
            prime.append(nextNum) 
            nextNum += 1
        else:
            nextNum += 1
        num += 1

print(prime)
```

There is now a rang function defined for improved readability and the all function in the if statement.

Comment: You can remove `for n in rang:` because the `all` function is already iterating over every `n` in `rang`.

Comment: Also, the definition of `rang` seems not quite right. For example, if `nextNum` is 101, then you want to test the *primes that are less than 10* (square root of 101, rounded down). But your `rang` instead takes the *first 10 primes*.